# jQuery $(this) out of scope when binding click event (Object Literal)

Tags: jquery, bind

I am having issues trying to get `$(this)` when I bind a `click` event on jQuery.

Inside `ActivateEditMode` I get: `SelectedSectionID` = `undefined` and `$(this)` equals to:

[image]

which I believe is not the anchor I am trying to get.

```js
var Section = {
  Init: function() {
    this.BindActions();
  },

  BindActions: function() {
    $('li.default a.cw_section_edit').on('click', this.ActivateEditMode.bind(event));
  },

  ActivateEditMode: function(Event) {
    Event.preventDefault();
    var SelectedSectionID = $(this).data('sectionid');
    var Li = $(this).closest('li');
    Li.css('background', '#FDF5E6');
    $('#sortable-sections li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('sectionid') !== SelectedSectionID) {
        const bcolour = $(this).data('enabled') ? '#FFFFFF' : '#E5E5E5';
        $(this).css('background', bcolour);
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
      Section.Init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable-sections">
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="31">
    <div class="grid_2">CRE</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Credito</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_31" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="31" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="32">
    <div class="grid_2">SAL</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Sales</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_32" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="32" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="37">
    <div class="grid_2">OT</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Other</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_37" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="37" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] from it

Comment: Remove `.bind(event)` from the event handler. You don't need it. `.on('click', this.ActivateEditMode)`

Comment: I was also suspicious of that one

Comment: `.bind(event)` makes `this == event`, so you can't use `$(this)` to access the clicked element.

Comment: In the `ActivateEditMode` function I need to use `event.preventDefault()`. So, I cannot remove `.bind(event)` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That's my point. The event is passed as an argument regardless. Calling bind() is redundant

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hey thanks, you are right, I can access `event` inside the function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have also added your comment to the selected answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **event.target** to instead of **$(this)** get the current clicked element. Because this is now referes to your section object.

```js
var Section = {
  Init: function() {
    this.BindActions();
  },

  BindActions: function() {
    $('li.default a.cw_section_edit').on('click', this.ActivateEditMode);
  },

  ActivateEditMode: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var SelectedAnchor = $(event.target);
    var SelectedSectionID = SelectedAnchor.data('sectionid');
    console.log('SelectionId', SelectedSectionID);
    var Li = SelectedAnchor.closest('li');
    Li.css('background', '#FDF5E6');
    $('#sortable-sections li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('sectionid') !== SelectedSectionID) {
        const bcolour = $(this).data('enabled') ? '#FFFFFF' : '#E5E5E5';
        $(this).css('background', bcolour);
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
      Section.Init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable-sections">
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="31">
    <div class="grid_2">CRE</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Credito</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_31" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="31" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="32">
    <div class="grid_2">SAL</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Sales</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_32" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="32" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="default cw_td_section_row" data-sectionid="37">
    <div class="grid_2">OT</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Other</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Yes</div>
    <div class="grid_2">
      <a href="#" id="cw_section_edit_37" class="cw_section_edit" data-sectionid="37" data-enabled="1">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```